# How to add successive rows of Layouts one by one in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

this is my first time asking something around here :)

Let's get to the thread: I'm trying to do the typical "Tap here to add another person".
The "person" is another field so I've got already 4 rows for name input, but I want to add one by one until 8 (four more, one each time you tap the "button").

**The debug:** When I press the Layout, it will make appear the 5th contributor, but If I tap again, it won't appear any contributor else. Any idea of how to fix this?

**This is my ".xml":**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <!-- Layout del form -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        [...] //Some Layouts

        <!-- Contributor 1 Layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContributorLayout_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NameLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- Name Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:text="@string/Contributor_Name1_Str"
                android:textSize="17dip" />

            <!-- Input Name -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputPart_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.55"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Contributor 2 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 1


        <!-- Contributor 3 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 1


        <!-- Contributor 4 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 1


        <!-- Contributor 5 Layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContributorLayout_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ContributorLayout_4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <!-- Name Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:text="@string/Contributor_Name5_Str"
                android:textSize="17dip" />

            <!-- Input Name -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputContributor_5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.55"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Contributor 6 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 5 // AKA Visibility = GONE

        <!-- Contributor 7 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 5 // AKA Visibility = GONE

        <!-- Contributor 8 Layout -->

        [...] //Just as the Contributor 5 // AKA Visibility = GONE

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Layout Inferior del form. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SubLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/InputLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Add_Colab_Field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_event"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_colab" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text="@string/Add_Colab_Field"
                android:textSize="17dip" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Button Create Event -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddEvent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Add_Colab_Field"
            android:text="@string/Add_Event_Bttn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is my "class":**

```
// Click en el botón add_colab_field
    LinearLayout add_colab_field = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Add_Colab_Field);
    add_colab_field.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final LinearLayout colab5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ContributorLayout_5);
            final LinearLayout colab6 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ContributorLayout_6);
            final LinearLayout colab7 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ContributorLayout_7);
            final LinearLayout colab8 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ContributorLayout_8);
            // Si presionamos el botón añadir...
            // Añadimos una nueva línea de participante

            if (colab5.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                colab5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (colab5.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
                    && colab6.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                colab6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (colab6.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
                    && colab7.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                colab7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (colab7.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
                    && colab8.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                colab8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Best regards, Guillermo.

Comment: This is not answers your question, but rather a suggestion: add layouts dynamically from code on demand. Do not store unnecessary and duplicate layouts in xml as they may not become visible at all, but affect performance and waste memory. Also, read about how to re-use identical layouts with <include /> http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking coblab5 visibility twice..According to your logic you should do `else if (colab5.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && colab6.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
 colab6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

And do consider @Alexander Zhak's comment.

Comment: typo mistake, in my code is alright and still not working.
About @Alexander Zhak I'm reading right now about it, but I'm concerned about how to give them the exactly ids I want, because I'll be receiving data from them later.

Comment: It can be done in several ways e.g., You can maintain a List of layouts and through indexes you can get the right EditText string or you can give Id's programmatically while adding new layouts.

Comment: So, it would be stupid to put the Layouts from 1 to 8 (Only the layout, not the content) and import them to the .xml with personal ids just like this method: `<include android:id=”@+id/colab_X(1,2,3..)”
         layout=”@layout/title”/>`  and then fill the layouts dynamically?
Is that the idea you're trying to explain from the start?

Comment: Hmm...well what I'm trying to say is that you can have one layout like your contributor layout 1 and add the programmatically in you linear layout by using addView method. While adding you can specify a unique ID's (could be 1,2...) to your editexts and then retrieve them by providing same id's. Does it make sense to you. Otherwise I can provide you an example :)

Comment: Yes, that example would be pretty useful because I'm just starting in Android and I feel sometimes somehow lost. 
Thanks a lot :)
But I feel like you're trying to make a LinearLayout in which you're going to code in the class one by one every single editTexts and TextViews. Am I right? :S

Comment: Did you still need the example...sorry got busy in my own project :(

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to see how would you do that.
I'll explain you how I'm doing it right now so you can see if I'm going through the right way or not: In the ".xml" I erased almost everything and right now, where there were the layouts "ContributorLayout_X...", there's just a LinearLayout, which is the container of the programmatically EditViews, EditTexts, etc...

Then, in the class, I add the fields programmatically with bucles for, and in the public onClick for the button "Add another contributor" I've done the same to add one by one the fields.

Comment: Now, the point is that I don't know how to receive the data from the fields, for example, in the "onClick" I create them like this:`int width = display.getWidth() / 2;
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(Add_EventActivity.this);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);l.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 15);TextView tV = new TextView(Add_EventActivity.this);tV.setText(getText(R.string.Contributor_Name_Str) + " " + num_clicks + ":"); EditText eT = new EditText(Add_EventActivity.this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); l.addView(tV, lp); l.addView(eT, lp); ll.addView(l);`

Comment: You are doing great...the only thing left is you need to get the right edit text. I'll recommend you to make a list of EditTexts. e.g. List<EditText> editList = new List<EditText>(); and then add your editTexts to editList. 
On retrieving you can simply do ((EditText)editList.get(1)).getText().toString(); // to get the first edit text.

Answer (score 0):

The first `else if` checks for a condtion that never can be true: `colab5` can't be visible **and**  invisible at the same time. You probably meant to write `colab6` for the second condition.

Comment: Sorry about that, as I replied before, it was a typo mistake. But still not working.